# Get Metrics for Soft layer resources

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are looking for API on getting disk related metrics of soft-layer something like Read / Write count.

From documentation it looks like using monitoring service we can get them but that's in beta and we need to activate those services

*Updated*

Here is how GCP provides metric APIs: cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute, wanted something on same line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you refer to metrics similar to the image below?

[image: Monitoring agent report]

If so, this is obtained through 2 ways:

1st When placing the order, if you select one of the 3 options displayed the advanced monitoring will be installed and started when provision is completed.

[image]

Basic option selected above has at least: Cpu, ***Disk*** (if you refer to metrics related to this) and Memory, Monitoring Agent, etc.

2nd If you navigate to https://control.softlayer.com/devices/monitoring 
and click on "Add Monitoring" on Advanced column, then you could order this but you will have to install manually the Nimsoft monitoring app. (http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/install-nimsoft-monitoring-robot)

Or if it´s nothing related to what´s above, please update the question with an image attachment of what do you require specifically on the Portal UI.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for option 1 but via calling API,
Here is how GCP provides metric APIs : https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute

Comment: Currently you`ll only be able to get information using the Api, just like you get through the portal UI, please let me know if you still require the Api call as it will retrieve data to be graphed through https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent/getGraph/ and return graph data just like the image, take in count that portal doesn´t return metrics like GCP as you could verify through it.